# Perform action in android app via Google Assistant

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I am developing a video Streaming android app. I want to play/pause the video using the Google Assistant. Like if user tells the google assistant to pause the video, i want to perform that action in my app.

I have read Google Assistant documents. There was options to have a conversation within the Google Assistant using DialogFlow and Action SDk. But there was nothing that can peroform any action in my app.
is there any way of do it.